# Access Forbidden Error in XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

**Access forbidden!**

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
Error 403

HELP!

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to activate any plugin in my wordpress site in localhost (XAMPP) which I cloned from my live site. And same error I am getting when I am trying to change setting/reading options.

HELP!

Comment: Please paste your htaccess code here.

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions on the plugin folder, make sure it is readable by the web server.

Comment: I am Newie, So Can You elaborate Please